# Are there any standards we can use to communicate math, e.g. ISO standards, does Category Theory aim eventually to be something like this?

Tags: proof-writing, category-theory, notation

I'm finding it difficult to read and express ideas in a standard way, I'm working in Computer Science and there are so many different math languages ways of communicating ideas. Is there a standard format for communicating math ideas, e.g. proof structures and notation, wordings, will Category Theory eventually be this standard?

Comment: It you want, sure, for you. Fortunately, nothing from category theory will bother the way each of us (you included) wants to communicate mathematics.

Comment: I think I get your point, your saying maths is about freedom to express ideas formally in different ways, but standards help with communication and reuse of ideas, maybe this should be a question for computer science information engineering?

Comment: I usually don't favor closing questions, and I think that yours is quite fine. That was just my opinion. Yes, fortunately we do have freedom in mathematics. But if CT is the way for you or anybody else, that is completely fine. Let's hear more opinions. By the way, Galois was here much before Eilenberg and Mac Lane, so it is not that we were forced to "invent" CT.

Comment: Can you give an example of different "math languages"?

Comment: @JohnB  could you elaborate on what you mean with the reference to Galois?

Comment: This would benefit a lot from examples of what you're grappling with. Depending on what you have in mind, I could imagine answers ranging from "oh, here's the page for the journal that standardizes communication norms" to "here's why it's good that we don't standardize that" to "here's a recommended standard for how Emglish grammar should interact with math" to [exactly Ittay Weiss's answer] to "there is a list of standards and here's a book on proof that covers them" to "it's unfortunate that that's not standardized but [something subfield-specific]" to "CS doesn't follow math's standard"...

Comment: @IttayWeiss As you seem to know, from what you write, but it is well known anyways, Eilenberg and Mac Lane's construction would not exist without Galois' work. So, yes, CT is completely unnecessary, because of Galois's work and from innumerous other works.

Comment: @JohnB I'm afraid I don't understand what you are aiming at. I don't see how the fact that a piece of mathematics built on ideas present in another piece of work renders the former completely unnecessary. I would also like to comment that your choice of words may come across is seeking confrontation.

Comment: @JohnDouma Sure by languages I also mean different systems, theories, formalisms, calculi, algebras etc. So Set theory would be one, that operates at a low level, category theory is another which operates a lower level I believe but can also operate at any level, Boolean algebra is another, predicate logic, basically any system in math.

Comment: @MarkS. I'm working on programming language semantics, for formal verification.

Comment: Sorry, I should have used more precise words than "grappling with". Basically, what are examples of things you're finding difficult to read due to lack of standardization (in the field of computer science/math you mentioned? though your original question didn't restrict to that field)? What are examples of things you're finding difficult to express, etc.? I've read a few papers on programming language semantics, but it's hard to think of how to address your question without knowing what are examples of problems you're looking for a solution to.

Comment: I certainly do hope that more people will get comfortable with the language of categories in the future...

Answer (score 0):

There is certainly not one single standards. Not even within one single sub-discipline. This is probably for similar reasons as to why there is not a single programming language (even for a particular purpose). Even within one single programming language there are different styles of programming. Some styles are considered better than others. Some of these judgements are supported by good reasoning, and some are cultural. Such a situation is also similar to what happens with natural languages. There is no standard English for instance. But even in languages that do adopt a standard, like French, there are still enumerably many styles of expression.

Mathematics communication is done through a mixture of natural and formal languages. Typically, English and naive set theory, respectively. These set some standards, but only very rudimentary ones. Within those standards mathematical ideas are communicated in a plethora of fashions.

One has to keep in mind that the language of set theory as a standard for mathematics communication is relatively new. Just over a century since the birth of set theory. There were, probably, some initial hopes that soon all of mathematics will be formalised in set theory and all questions will be resolved with classical logic. Today we know that such an expectation was naive. Surely, set theory can provide for a foundation of mathematics in the sense that anything you want to say probably can be encoded only using set theory. However, how useful such an encoding is for the communication of mathematics is debatable. Again referring to computer science, just because every program can be encoded in assembly, does not mean one needs to know how to do that. Or care much that it can be done. We find it very useful to abstract programming paradigms and there is no reason to think that the best one will be the one the most closely mimics the physical reality of how a computer computes.

As for category theory. It is not an explicit aim of category theory to form such a standard. One remarkable thing about category theory is that as a language it as expanding organically very rapidly. It is likely that many concepts from category theory will eventually become standard vocabulary in mathematics, computer science, and physics (and maybe some other areas). Arguably, adjunctions are so ubiquitous that not knowing their basic abstract properties is a handicap.

Again going back to programming languages, the popularity of some languages is largely a matter of just popularity. Such languages come in and out of fashion. Languages that are genuinely good, tend to stick around. This is more true of programming paradigms. There are hundreds of languages. Each probably has a fair amount of followers, but only some have a long lasting amount of followers. In other words, if you build it they will come. If you build it well they will stay.

In mathematics we do not have as many languages as in computer science. It is very hard to build a mathematical language. In a sense, set theory is but the first language for mathematics. There are some dialects of it. Category theory as a language can be seen as the second iterate. It's merely language number 2 for mathematics. Mac Lane and Eilenberg built it. Homology theorists used it. Then computer scientists used it. Then logicians used it. Then algebraists used it. Then physicists used it. It appears to be a convenient language. It catches rapidly. Will it stick? My personal opinion is a massive yes.

Comment: -1 You seem to confuse popularity with choice. Fortunately dictators are not preferred because of choice.

Comment: I find your comment very unclear. If you care to elaborate I'll be happy to listen (to non-confrontational speech). Its second part is clearly meant to evoke rather than inform. So, your objection to my entire (rather long answer), that you find is so bad that it merits a down-vote, is summed up by 7 words. I'm happy to take any criticism if I can learn something from it. Your current conduct appears to be seeking a fight. If not, my apologies. If so, please accept my apologies in advance for ignoring similarly poised comments.